# Unable to access data from localhost with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, localhost

I'm using JQuery to access some data and and a PHP file in WWW folder of localhost. I'm sending id to the php file and i want some details regarding that id.

When i use this code inside Intel XDK. Then it is showing perfect inside mobile view but in the browser its not working.

Any type of help will be appreciated.

Index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>jQuery PHP Json Response</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    div
    {
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    }

    #msg {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    }
    .members {
    width: 500px ;
    background-color: beige;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="msg">
    <table id="userdata" border="1">
    <thead>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Latitude</th>
    <th>Longitude</th>

    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var result = prompt("Enter a address");
        $.post("http://localhost/getuser.php", { str : result }, function(json) {
            alert(json);

            $.each($.parseJSON(json), function(idx, obj) {
        alert(obj.id);

        var tblRow =
                    "<tr>"
                +"<td>"+obj.id+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+obj.lat+"</td>"
                +"<td>"+obj.lng+"</td>"

                +"</tr>" ;
                $("#userdata tbody").append(tblRow);

            });

    });


    });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And, in WWW folder getuser.php

```
<?php
    $host="localhost"; //replace with your hostname 
    $username="root"; //replace with your username 
    $password="auroin"; //replace with your password 
    $db_name="map"; //replace with your database 
//  $str = $_REQUEST['str'];
    $str = $_POST['str'];
    //$str = 1;
    $con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql = "select * from pet where id='".$str."'"; //replace emp_info with your table name 
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $json = array();

    while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)){
    $json[] = $row;

    }
    mysql_close($db_name);
    //echo '{"members":'.json_encode($json).'}';
    echo json_encode($json);

    // please refer to our PHP JSON encode function tutorial for learning json_encode function in detail 
?>
```

#### EDIT:-

Some errors are I'm getting in my console ...

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.  `index.html`

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at getuser.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.     `getuser.php`

Comment: 'It's not working' is not enough detail for us to help you. Have you checked the console for errors? Have you debugged the server-side code to make sure the request is received? Is any data being returned?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yes server side code is returning data , i have checked by localhost/getuser.php . and its returning . sorry i'm totally new about these things..

Comment: @user3812200 Consider using console.log(json) instead of alert(json) in your code. console.log gives better visual output than alert. Moreover, add here a screen copy of this "data" returned by your server

Comment: are you on http://localhost/index.html or is it another host ?

Comment: @syl.fabre , No index.html is at other place php file is on localhost/index.html...

Comment: @Debflav, but in mobile view in Intel XDK it working perfectly. but in bowser  alert(json); is also not comming , which is before $.each()...

Comment: @user3812200 I don't understand your reply. Can you give the full url of both index.html and getuser.php please? "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" means that you cannot have http://domain1/index.html query for http://domain2/getuser.php

Comment: @syl.fabre, file:///home/auroin/Desktop/index.html     and     http://localhost/getuser.php

Comment: that's why it's not working security policy of the browser blocks the AJAX request. Search for "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" to understand this issue

Comment: @syl.fabre, Hey buddy i'm totally stuck with Cross-Origin Request Blocked. Any help regarding this ...

Comment: you have to access index.html like http://localhost/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you disable the same-origin policy in your browser in order to test cross domain AJAX request from a local file.

For example, with Google Chrome on Windows you can disable this policy by launching chrome with the following command :

C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security

Together, both of these flags will allow you to test cross-domain ajax requests from a local file.